# How to upgrade a postgres database from 9.3 to 9.4 on heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This is a question for heroku staff.  I have a database running postgres 9.3.  When will heroku offer 9.4 that was released last week?  Is there an upgrade guide?  And is there a best practice way of converting json to jsonb columns with minimum downtime?  Thanks!

Comment: As of 2014-12-28, 9.4 support hasn't been announced (https://blog.heroku.com/archives), upgrade docs hasn't been updated (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases). Procedure would likely be similar to 9.2 -> 9.3 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

As told [here](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/postgres-9-4-beta-access/818), You can try out 9.4 by passing the `--version=9.4` flag:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --version=9.4
```

To upgrade your database:

1. dump your data
2. upgrade your postgresql heroku instance
3. update your postgresql schema (json to jsonb...)
4. reload your data

You could also try `pg_upgrade`.

As of 23rd of April 2015, [postgresql 9.4 is available on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/4/23/postgres-94-general-availability).